# Save gridster layout using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

I am creating dashboard application with Gridster: https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

I would like to save my layout to database using JSON. What I do know, is that I store charts array to database and fetch it. Is it possible to store widget col,row and size to specific widget so I could then give the size-x and size-y with angular style {{chart.xsize}}. When creating widget I could then assign default size values and save only after user has resized or dragged widget. Or is this completely wrong way to do this? How else I could store the widget sizes and positions to database?

I have ng-repeat for my widgets like this:

```
  <div ng-if="chart.type === settings.types.LINEAR_GAUGE">
      <div class="panel c8y" gridster-item size-x="2" size-y="1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">{{chart.title}}</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs" ng-click="onClickDelete($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"/></button>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <c8y-linear-gauge dp="chart.dp" measurement="chart.data[0].measurement"/>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually built several angular dashboards using angular-gridster, and save the layout back to the database. Here is how I do it:

```
    <div gridster="gridsterOpts">
        <ul>
                <li
                    gridster-item
                    row="element.posY"
                    col="element.posX"
                    size-x="element.width"
                    size-y="element.height"
                    ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index">
                    <div class="element-title">
                        <!--some header stuff goes here-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-useable-area">
                        <!--Main widget stuff goes here-->
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So I have an array called `elements` where I am storing my widget objects. Each object in the array includes properties for the height and width and size. So, something like this:

```
{
    posY: 0,
    posX: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    templateUrl: ...,
    data: ...
}
```

Fortunately because of angular binding, when the user changes the gidster item size or position, it changes the property value too! Its important to note that the `elements` array is appended to a $sessionStorage object from the [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) framework I use, so that all the changes will be persisted if the page refreshes.

Eventually, when the user saves the dashboard, I write an object to the database which includes the `elements` array. Thus saving all the location and size info. The next time you call that object from the database, and populate the `elements` array with its data, you get back the same dashboard.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was thinking to do, but my logic was just bit wrong. Now it saves the layout and sizes nicely!

Comment: @Shnigi help me if u can on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769507/align-gridster-items-using-row-and-col-values-angularjs